# Redirect to HTTPS with exeption of one url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, redirect, https

I need to force redirect all pages to https, except of one. But on prod server it fails in infinite redirect loop.

It ignores exception url and redirects just all

Server has apache and nginx installed.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/novinki [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /novinki [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

UPD

This code works locally, but on prod it forces https to all pages
(`THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI`)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/novinki [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Apache config (partly):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>

    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>

    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name {domain};
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/{domain}/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/{domain}.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/{domain}.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/roots/data/www/{domain};
    root $root_path;
    listen {ip}:80;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
}
server {
    server_name {domain};
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/roots/{domain}";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/roots/{domain}";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset off;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/{domain}/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/{domain}.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/{domain}.com.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/roots/data/www/{domain};
    root $root_path;
    listen {ip}:443 ssl;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: _“Server has apache and nginx installed”_ - so you’re using one to proxy the other then? Share some relevant config details then maybe. And you have the same setup on your local dev system where it works, or is that different in major aspects (like _not_ having a proxy for example)? Have you enabled rewrite logging to try and figure out what is going on that way?

Comment: @misorude I added nginx and apache configs. On my local machine I just have apache+windows and it redirects as I want. I try to enable rewrite logging - didn't know it is possible.